# Angular Circular Dependencies with Dynamic Nested Components

Tags: angular, typescript, circular-dependency

I have looked all over the internet for a resolution to this to no avail (different cases etc.) so please forgive the code dump below, the problem I am having is to do with circular dependencies. The code dump is to provide the context.

Side note: I am fairly new to Angular and Typescript.

#### The Concept

I am trying to build a set of nested components that all extend a base class to simplify coding, of course. These components can contain children of any of each other. To load the child components, the base class uses a directive which needs to decide which component to load in its place. The best example is to think of nesting `<div>` and `<section>` blocks.

Here's my code:

##### The directive `directive.ts`

Loads its respective component when `load()` is called

```
import { ComponentFactoryResolver, Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

import { DivComponent } from './div'; // < -- Part of the dependency issues
import { SectionComponent } from './section'; // < -- Part of the dependency issues

@Directive({
    selector: '[child-node]',
})
export class ChildNodeDirective {

    @Input() type: string;
    @Input() content: any;

    constructor(
        private container: ViewContainerRef,
        private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    ){}

    load(): void {

        let component: Type<any>;

        switch (this.type) {
            case 'div' : component = DivComponent; break;
            case 'section' : component = SectionComponent; break;
        }

        if (component) {
            const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
            const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
            componentRef.instance.content = this.content;
        }

    }

}
```

##### The base class `base.ts`

This class is the base for all the components which;

1. Uses `@ViewChildren` and `ngAfterContentChecked` to load its child directives,
2. Sets `childNodes` when `set content` is invoked so that the component can render its `<child-node>` elements

```
import { AfterContentChecked, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';

import { ChildNodeDirective } from './directive'; // < -- Part of the dependency issues

export abstract class Base implements AfterContentChecked {

    // These are elements that the template will render into the directive
    public childNodes: {[type: string]: any} = {};

    private childrenLoaded = false;

    @ViewChildren(ChildNodeDirective) protected children?: QueryList<any>;

    ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
        if (!this.childrenLoaded && this.children) {
            this.children.forEach((child: ChildNodeDirective) => {
                child.load();
            });
            this.childrenLoaded = true;
        }
    }

    set content(content: any) {
        this.childNodes = content.childNodes;
    }

}
```

##### The div component `div.ts`

This component extends the base and simply renders its child nodes

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Base } from './base'; // < -- Part of the dependency issues

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-div',
    templateUrl: './div.html',
})
export class DivComponent extends Base {

    public textContent: string;

    set content(content: any) {

        super.content = content;

        this.textContent = content.text;

    }

}
```

##### The div template `div.html`

```
<div>{{ textContent }}</div>

<div *ngFor="let child of childNodes">
  <ng-template child-node [content]="child.content" [type]="child.type"></ng-template>
</div>
```

---

#### TL;DR The Problem

All of this seems to work. I am able to produce all kinds of content and deep nesting of children etc. I cannot speak to the "correctness" of the code / implementation but the only issue I am having is circular dependency warnings.

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
div.ts -> base.ts -> directive.ts -> div.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
section.ts -> base.ts -> directive.ts -> section.ts
```

PLEASE help me get rid of them...

#### SOLUTION

Based on Kai's last advise, I created a decorator to collect the meta data for use inside the directive.

Changes in `directive.ts`

```
export const HtmlElementMap: {component: Type<any>, map: string[]}[] = [];

export function HtmlComponent(config: {map: string[]}) {
    return (target: Type<any>) => {
        ElementMap.push({component: target, map: config.map});
    };
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[child-node]',
})
export class ChildNodeDirective {

    ...

    load(): void {

        let component: Type<any>;

        HtmlElementMap
          .filter(v => v.map.indexOf(this.type) > -1)
          .forEach(
              v => {
                  if (undefined === component) {
                      component = v.component;
                  }
              }
          );

        if (component) {
            const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
            const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
            componentRef.instance.content = this.content;
        }

    }

}
```

And `div.ts` as well as subsequent components

```
@HtmlComponent({map: ['div']})
@Component({
    selector: 'custom-div',
    templateUrl: './div.html',
})
export class DivComponent extends Base {

   .
   .
   .

}
```

Comment: When Itry this I get an error "Cannot access 'HtmlElementMap' before initialization". How did you get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion the red line in my diagramm is the problem here. So you can try to solve and remove this dependency if you register your components (need for the switch statement) during runtime. For example `Base` class can collect all available components and pass them to the `ChildNodeDirective` class. Or you can use a service to register them. If you have a working stackblitz sample, we can help you with the code.

[image]

Comment: I LOVE your picture XD So you're suggesting creating a provider, on construct of section/div register self and then get the same provider in the directive to access the map? I'll try that out, if it works I'll mark as correct. I didn't think of that... You're a hero!

Comment: @Prof83 Exactly. It may be not the cleanest solution but it sounds okay for me and i cannot think of a better one for the moment.

Comment: @kai I also like the graphic very much. What did you use to create it?

Comment: @Fab2 Thanks, i created it with the awsome open source tool https://excalidraw.com/

Comment: @kai I have updated my question with a new issue, we are almost there. Just how to combat the registry not being constructed?

Comment: @Prof83 Oops, thats a detail i forgot about :/ But i have a solution for that which is even cleaner than using an angular service and DI. Use a decorator something like `@HtmlComponent()`. This decorator received the class and can get the string name like `div` as a parameter. And inside the decorator you can create your registry and import it into `ChildNodeDirective` without using DI.

Comment: @kai that worked perfectly. Updating my question and I will mark your answer as correct